# Symfony4: validation contraints translation are not applied

Tags: symfony, symfony4, orocrm

### Context

I am working on a Symfony 4 application, with an OroPlatform overlay.

I have followed this tutorial : https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/validation/translations.html

Here is my code :

```php
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Baltimore\Bundle\AppBundle\Repository\SubscriptionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_subscription")
 */
class Subscription
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="author.name.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $number;

}
```

As you can see, I have put this line to change to default `NotBlank` message `@Assert\NotBlank(message="author.name.not_blank")`

### Issue

My current locale is `fr_FR`, I have check with the following code :

```php
<?php
$locale = $request->getLocale();
```

Here is my `translations/validators.fr_FR.xlf` (path is relative to the project root directory) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="author.name.not_blank">
                <source>author.name.not_blank</source>
                <target>Veuillez entrer un nom d'auteur</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Cache is cleared `symfony console cache:clear`

But nothing change, the error message is `author.name.not_blank` instead of my translation.

[image]

The output of the command line `php bin/console debug:translation fr BaltimoreAppBundle` :

[image]

Comment: Try changing the filename to `validators.fr.xlf` and then refresh your cache again.

Comment: Still the same after the change to `validators.fr.xlf`..

Comment: Wait, you actually changed this to French, right? `<target>Please enter an author name.</target>`

Comment: Hahaha not yet because I have just followed the Symfony tutorial!

As you can see on the screenshot.. I can see the translation "key" but not the value associated with it..

Comment: Try running `php bin/console debug:translation fr`. As far as I can tell you're following the tutorial correctly but it's behaving as if it can't see that xlf file...

Comment: I have updated my post with the output of the command. It seems that Symfony can't see the key in my Entity file..

Comment: There is no way your app is using the `fr` locale, you should get default constraints messages in french, and that's not the case according to your screenshot. Check either the `config.yml` or the `parameters.yml` and change the `locale` parameter to `fr`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to came from the fact that OroPlatform have his own command line to update translation.

Here is my working configuration :

```yaml
# /translations/validators.fr_FR.yml
This value should not be blank.: Cette valeur ne doit pas être vide
```

Then, I run these commands : `php bin/console clear:cache` and `php bin/console oro:translation:dump`

Now I can see my updated translation.